# How to access switch argument / ID from switch?

Tags: python, callback, kivy, args

Please forgive if my question isnt placed properly, i am new to this whole subject. In my python file i have a callback function for my switches, which i create in my .kv file.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.pagelayout import PageLayout

class PageLayout(PageLayout): 
    statusMsg = 'Empty Status.'

    def switch_callback(self, switchObject, switchValue):
        #Switch values are True and False
        if(switchValue):
            statusMsg = '{0} enabled'.format(switchObject)
            print(statusMsg)
        else:
            statusMsg = '{0} disabled'.format(switchObject)
            print(statusMsg)
        return statusMsg

    def __init__(self): 
        super(PageLayout, self).__init__() 

class myGUI(App):
    def build(self):
        return PageLayout()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myGUI().run()
```

Kivy File (myGUI.kv):

```
<PageLayout>:
    BoxLayout:
        BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text: 'TestLabel'
        Switch:
            id: switchCal
            active: False
            on_active: root.switch_callback(*args)
```

now i can print the called object argument but not the id. Do i have to use another variable, or is id not passed with *args? My shell looks like this:

```
<kivy.uix.switch.Switch object at 0x1111B258> enabled
```

I tried switchObject.id but it doesnt work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can find the id of the object, but the way to do it depends on the rest of your code (e.g. who is the parent of `Switch` etc.). Please add a [mcve]..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to find the switch's `id`, is a `for loop` with the `root`'s `ids`.

```py
        for i_d in self.ids:
            if switchObject == self.ids[i_d]:
                print(i_d)
                break
```

You have also to rename your `PageLayout` class to something else, because its name conflicts with kivy's `PageLayout`.

Full code for the `py` part:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.pagelayout import PageLayout

class PageLayoutX(PageLayout):
    statusMsg = 'Empty Status.'

    def switch_callback(self, switchObject, switchValue):
        for i_d in self.ids:
            if switchObject == self.ids[i_d]:
                print(i_d)
                break
        # Switch values are True and False
        if (switchValue):
            statusMsg = '{0} enabled'.format(switchObject)
            print(statusMsg)
        else:
            statusMsg = '{0} disabled'.format(switchObject)
            print(statusMsg)
        return statusMsg

    def __init__(self):
        super(PageLayoutX, self).__init__()


class myGUI(App):
    def build(self):
        return PageLayoutX()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    myGUI().run()
```

... and the `kv` part

```py
<PageLayoutX>:
    BoxLayout:
        BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text: 'TestLabel'
        Switch:
            id: switchCal
            active: False
            on_active: root.switch_callback(*args)
```

Comment: thanks alot! I will try it soon and tell you how it went :)